# Как применить измененный css-стиль функцией jquery .css() для всех элементов с одинаковым id?

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Собственно, есть код, который меняет css при загрузки страницы, как сделать что бы все элементы id="box" применяли новый стиль и стали черными?

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#box {
    background: #6699FF;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
</style>

<div id = "box"></div><br>
<div id = "box"></div><br>
<div id = "box"></div><br>
<div id = "box"></div><br>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#box").css("background-color", "black" ); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Уберите id и установите для всех элементов class.

P.S. Если бы платили по одному баксу каждый раз за напоминание того, что "**id - это уникальный элемент и может быть в одном экземпляре**", то я был бы миллионером ))

Comment: <div id = "box"></div><br>
можно узнать зачем там перевод строки?

Comment: Deonis, спасибо, добавил class и все сработало =) 
koza4ok, что бы строка между блоками была, так эстетичные на вид мне показалось...

Comment: Так никто не делает....Растояние будет отличатся в разных браузерах.Для этого существуют свойства margin-top||margin-bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перейдите на классы:

```
<style type="text/css">
.box {
    background: #6699FF;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
</style>

<div class = "box"></div><br>
<div class = "box"></div><br>
<div class = "box"></div><br>
<div class = "box"></div><br>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( "div.box" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "black" ); 
});
</script>
```

**p.s.** не тестировал, но думаю должно работать.

Comment: @IVsevolod, а цикл зачем?